# How to display empty tableview by default when using UISearchController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using UISearchController to provide a search functionality in my app. The user can type for location, or if clicks on Use current location, i will get the location.

But when clicking on Search, the editable search field and cancel button appear and dim the background. The table view appears only on typing a character.

How do i display the table view as soon as user clicks on Search?

The way I am creating a UISearch controller here is like this:

```
let locationController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchController)
locationController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(locationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note: I am not using UISearchResultsUpdating method. I am using custom delegate to reload the table view from the parent ViewController.

I want to show Last 2 options in the 2nd image as soon as user clicks Search
See attached snapshots.

[image: On Clicking Search Icon]
[image: I want to show Last 2 options as soon as user clicks Search]

Comment: You can take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790244/uisearchcontroller-show-results-even-when-search-bar-is-empty

Comment: @Onur, thanks for the link, but i could not get it to work. No matter what, on clicking search, the table view is still hidden. But if i click Space or any other character, the table appears.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123675/341994